# Django staticfiles aren't loading in production

Tags: python, django, fastcgi

I've been using Django for awhile now, but I'm very new to putting sites into production. I'm unfortunately with a non-Django-friendly hosting service (HostGator) and set up Django using FastCGI and the tutorial [here](http://redconservatory.com/blog/getting-django-up-and-running-with-hostgator-part-1/). Django version is 1.3... :(

The site is up, but for some reason static files are failing to load. The debug output shows that files are being looked for at my_domain/static/, which I'm not sure is right.

I don't have access to edit any server configs or anything, so I can only solve this problem via Django code. I appreciate the help. (code will follow)

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = "/home2/mlinsenb/django/projects/website/media"

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = "/home2/mlinsenb/django/projects/website/static"

STATIC_URL = "/static/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = ()

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
'django.core.context_processors.debug',
'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
'django.core.context_processors.media',
'django.core.context_processors.static',
'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('homepage.views',
url(r'^$', 'home'),
url(r'^blog/$', 'blog'),
url(r'^programming/$', 'programming'),
url(r'^music/$', 'music'),
url(r'^about/$', 'about'),
url(r'^contact/$', 'contact'),

# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
# url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
# url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends "homepage/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Hi, I'm Max.</h1>
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/me.jpg" alt="Serious business" height="300px" width="300px">
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`staticfiles_urlpatterns()` is not designed for production and only works if `DEBUG = True`. You need to serve up the static files separately. I've never used django with fcgi, but I'm assuming you can pull this off relatively easily.

The files are being looked for at `yourdomain.com/static` because that is what you set for your `STATIC_URL`

First, change your `STATIC_ROOT` to a public directory. You should have something like `/home2/mlinsenb/public_html` where you put your `index.fcgi` file. Create a `static` directory here and change your `STATIC_ROOT = "/home2/mlinsenb/public_html/static"`

You may want to do the same for `MEDIA_ROOT` too incase you use it in the future.

Your .htaccess should look like this if you were following the guide you posted:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (media/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(admin/.*)$ index.fcgi/$1 [L]
```

Again, I'm no expert with mod_rewrite, but it looks like they handle the media files with that, so I would try adding one line for your static files:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (media/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteRule (static/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(admin/.*)$ index.fcgi/$1 [L]
```

Then run `python manage.py collectstatic` and django should put all of your static files in `/home2/mlinsenb/public_html/static`

Now hostgator should serve up files at yourdomain.com/static from that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku, among others, [recommend](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets#whitenoise) just letting Django serve your static files using a WSGI plugin. They used to recommend `dj-static`, now they recommend [whitenoise](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/whitenoise).